# How to invalidate TLB all in secure EL1 for ARM A53 CPU?

Tags: arm

Curious to know if there is any restriction to run TLB invalidate all (tlbi alle1is) from Secure EL1 running in 64B mode for ARM A53 (ARMv8-A) CPU? I see some comments at our software saying it will cause exception hence switching to EL3 to run the instruction.

I assume HCR_EL2.TTLB bit will not interfere for Secure EL1. Please let me know how can I run TLB invalidate all at secure EL1 without switching to EL3.

Thanks,
Debasish.

Answer (score 1):

"TLBI ALLEL1IS" instruction:

Invalidate all EL1&0 regime stage 1 and 2 TLB entries on all PEs in the same Inner Shareable domain.

If EL3 is implemented, the value of SCR_EL3.NS determines whether the instruction invalidates the translations that are associated with Secure address space, or invalidates the translations associated with the Non-secure address space.

This instruction is a 64-bit system instruction.

This instruction can be executed at the following exception levels:

- EL2 (NS)
- EL3 (SCR.NS=1)
- EL3 (SCR.NS=0)